# Example of a countably infinite set of measure zero that has a positive volume

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Definition: The volume of a bounded set $A\subset\mathbb R^n$ whose characteristic function $1_A$ is integrable over $\mathbb R^n$ is $\int_A 1_A$.

I'm looking for an example of a countably infinite bounded set that has a non-zero volume. (I know that such a set necessarily has measure zero.) This will then show that a countable set need not have volume zero.

Comment: what's "volume"?

Comment: If you mean Jordan outer content, then $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @StefanSmith Thanks for asking. I've added in the definition.

Comment: $\int_A 1_A$ is exactly the measure of $A$, which you already indicated is zero.

Answer (score 4):

If a set is Jordan measurable, then it is Lebsgue measurable and their measures agree. Thus, you cannot have a countable set that is Jordan measurable and is not of Jordan, hence Lebesgue, measure zero.

*To clarify* Let $A\subseteq {\bf R}^n$ be bounded. Without mention to the Lebesgue integral, we can define the Jordan content (or measure) of $A$ to be the value of the Riemann integral $$c(A)=\int_R \chi_A$$ where $R$ is any closed (bounded) rectangle (or "block", if you may) containing $A$ (observe Riemann integrals aren't defined for sets that are *not* closed blocks). We can then extend the definition of the Riemann integral, declaring a function $f:B\subseteq\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ to be Riemann integrable over a Jordan measurable set $A\subset B$ if $$\int_B f\cdot\chi_A$$ exists, in which case we denote this by $$\int_A f$$ In particular, the Jordan measure of $A$ is $$\int_A 1$$

As a side note, from Lebesgue's criterion of Riemann integrability, it follows that $A$ is Jordan measurable iff it's boundary $\partial A$ has measure zero: this is where $\chi_A$ is discontinuous. Since $\partial A$ is compact (being bounded, and closed), it has Lebesgue measure zero iff it has Jordan content zero, namely, iff given $\varepsilon >0$ it can be covered by *finitely many* open blocks whose volumes sum to less than $\varepsilon$.

Consequently, if the Riemann integral $$\int_R \chi_A=\int_A 1$$ exists then it exists as a Lebesgue integral, and it equals, sometimes by definition, sometimes as a theorem, the Lebsgue measure of $A$. Thus, if a set is Jordan measurable, it is Lebesgue measurable, and its measures coincide.

Comment: Volume zero implies measure zero. Where did you get that non-zero volume implies non-zero measure?

Comment: @Ryan You're saying the set is *countable*. Assuming it is Jordan measurable, it is Lebesgue measurable, and their measures agree. But since the set is countable, it has Lebesgue measure zero, hence Jordan measure zero.

Comment: @Ryan No, no. Volume zero implies measure zero, but not converesely.

Comment: @Ryan No, I am not. I am saying that if the set is Jordan measurable then it is Lebesgue measurable, and their measures agree. Since the set is countable, it has Lebesgue measure zero. Since the measures agree, it has Jordan measure zero.

Comment: " if the set is Jordan measurable then it is Lebesgue measurable"  This reads to me as "non-zero volume implies non-zero measure", or, equivalently, "measure zero implies volume zero."

Comment: @Ryan Could you clarify what you mean by "volume zero" and "measure zero"...?

Comment: Volume zero means the integral in the definition at the top of my post is zero.  Measure zero means the set can be covered by countably many hyperrectangles of arbitrarily small total volume.

Comment: @Ryan I have added something. Hope it clears out all confusion.