# Example of a set that has zero measure but nonzero volume.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

A set $E\subset R^n$ is said to have volume $0$ if; for every $\epsilon>0,$ there exists a finite family of rectangles $U_1,..,U_m$ such that;
$$E\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^mU_i$$
$$\text{and }\sum_{i=1}^m V(U_i)< \epsilon.$$

My book constructs an example of a set that has zero measure but a non-zero volume. It is given below;

Let $E$ be the set of rational numbers in the closed interval $[0,1]$. Then $E$ is countable, and so it has measure $0$. If the sets $U_i=[a_i,b_i]$ for $i=1,2,\dots,m$ cover $E$ then they will also cover $[0,1]$. Therefore, $$\chi_{[0,1]}(x)\leq\sum_{i=1}^m\chi_{[a_i,b_i]}(x).$$

Here $\chi_{[0,1]}(x)$ means that if $x\in[0,1],$ then it's either $1$ or $0,$ or I am mistaken?

Then;

$1=\int_0^1$$\chi_{[0,1]}(x)dx\leq\int_0\sum_i\chi_{[a_i,b_i]}(x)dx$
(why upper value of integral is not written?) $=\sum_{i=1}^m(b_i-a_i)$(how author get this?) $=\sum_{i=1}^m V(U_i)$

Can you please explain above parts.

Comment: Presumably measure = Lebesgue measure here. What is your definition of volume?

Comment: edited my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Example of a countably infinite set of measure zero that has a positive volume](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618172/example-of-a-countably-infinite-set-that-has-a-positive-volume)

Comment: @DietrichBurde No because I am not familar with Jordan measure yet.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719558/difference-between-volume-measure-zero-and-not-having-volume?rq=1).

Comment: Maybe but it still does not answer my other concrete questions.

Comment: Excuse me. I am terribly confused. Volume is just Lebesgue measure, no? I'm reading these definitions and they're claiming the volume of a set $A$ is the Riemann integral of its characteristic function, but whenever the Riemann integral exists so too does the Lebesgue integral exist and their values agree

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two typos in that, and perhaps a missing step as well. Try this:

$1=\int_0^1$$\chi_{[0,1]}(x)dx\leq\int_0^1\sum_i\chi_{[a_i,b_i]}(x)dx=\sum_{i=1}^m\int_0^1\chi_{[a_i,b_i]}(x)dx=\sum_{i=1}^m(b_i-a_i)=\sum_{i=1}^m V(U_i)$

Comment: Why $\int_0^1\chi_{[a_i,b_i]}(x)dx = b_i-a_i$

Comment: Here $\chi_{[0,1]}(x)$ means that if $x\in[0,1],$ then it's either $1$ or $0,$ or I am mistaken?

Comment: I can't make sense of that! $\chi_{[0,1]}(x)$ means $1$ if $x\in[0,1]$, and $0$ if $x\notin[0,1]$. So if $[a,b]\subseteq[0,1]$, then clearly $\int_0^1\chi_{[a,b]}(x)dx=b-a$.